# not able to fetch values from struct type channel in Go lang

Tags: go, goroutine

With reference to  [this](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools) example, i want to add a pre-defined delay between job initialization and termination. I have stored the data i.e. jobid and waittime in map. Then i have copied the entire map in a channel of same struct type as map. But i am not able to fetch the map values in go routine calls. Please help me, I am new to Go.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
id, waitime int
}

var m = map[int]Vertex{
1:  {1, 1000},
2:  {2, 2000},
3:  {3, 1000},
4:  {4, 2000},
5:  {5, 1000},
6:  {6, 2000},
7:  {7, 1000},
8:  {8, 2000},
9:  {9, 1000},
10: {10, 2000},
}

func worker(w int, jobs <-chan Vertex, results chan<- int) {
for j := 1; j <= len(m); j++ {
    a, b := <-jobs.id, <-jobs.waitime
    fmt.Println("worker", w, "started job", a)
    //time.Sleep(time.Sleep(time.Duration(b)))
    fmt.Println("worker", w, "finished job", a)
    results <- j * 2
  }
}

func main() {
//n := 5
jobs := make(chan Vertex, 100)
results := make(chan int, 100)

for w := 1; w <= 5; w++ {
    go worker(w, jobs, results)
}
fmt.Println(len(m))
for j := 1; j <= len(m); j++ {
    jobs <- m[j]
}
//close(jobs)

for a := 1; a <= len(m); a++ {
    <-results
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things are wrong with your code.

First, you can't access struct members directly off the channel. That is, this line is wrong:

```
a, b := <-jobs.id, <-jobs.waitime
```

`jobs` is a channel. It does not have any members called `id` or `waittime`. These are the members of the struct `Vertex` it's supposed to transfer. Change this line to:

```
job := <-jobs
a, b := job.id, job.waitime
```

But now, your code declares `b` but does not use it. To fix, uncomment the call to `time.Sleep`:

```
time.Sleep(time.Sleep(time.Duration(b))) !INCORRECT CALL
```

But this call is completely wrong. `time.Sleep` expects an argument of type `time.Duration` and returns nothing. To fix, make the following changes:

```
time.Sleep(time.Duration(b) * time.Millisecond)
```

This should get your code running.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
a, b := <-jobs.id, <-jobs.waitime
```

to:

```
job := <-jobs
a, b := job.id, job.waitime
```

`jobs` is a channel not a Vertex.